# Ajax unable to pass other variables with serialize()

Tags: ajax

What I am trying to achieve is making an Ajax call to the server to return some data whilst also taking into consideration what filters have been selected in my form ".searchfilters form". I am trying to pass variables along with a form serialize and am getting a syntax error unepected token . on page load. Have I merged the normal variables I want to pass along with the form.serialize in the wrong way? Also if there is a better method to applying filters to an ajax request im open to it but this is the main method I have found from online examples.

```
$(".sidebar-list-parent li a, .sidebar-list-child li a").click(function(){

var soundid = $(this).attr("soundid");
var soundidparent = $(this).attr("class");
var filters = $(".search-filters form");

$.ajax ({
type: 'GET',
data: {filters.serialize(), soundid:soundid, soundidparent:soundidparent, }
url: "audio-module.php",
 success: function(data) { 
$('.audio-modules-container').html(data);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
data: {filters.serialize(), soundid:soundid, soundidparent:soundidparent, }
```

to

```
data: {filters.serialize(), soundid:soundid, soundidparent:soundidparent },
```

Comment: Still getting the unexpected token unfortunately

Comment: `unexpected token` where? which line ? you need to provide that information in order to get proper help.

Comment: the . in filters.serialize() is the unexpected token

Comment: I guess you've to review `filters.serialize()`

Comment: I thought that was how you passed form input values in ajax data, no? I think its something to do with the way im combing serialize with the other two variables in data